# How can I know of strikes that affect public transport in Italy?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, italy, event-based-effects, industrial-action

tl;dr: **Is there a resource that warns me of upcoming strikes that affect public transport in Italy?**

Recently I was forced to change travel plans very last-minute upon learning of a railway strike. To be able to cope with such issues a little bit less at the last moment,

1. Is there a resource where upcoming strikes that affect trains, buses, flights, local public transport in Italy are announced in advance?
2. Bonus question: If trains are affected, is there a way to find out which connections will be guaranteed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend checking out the below links.
Hopefully these will tell you what you need to know.

Link 1:[Shows a categorical view of current planned strikes in Italy in the local public transport sector](http://www.cgsse.it/web/guest/scioperi-per-settore?p_p_id=settoriQuotati_WAR_FSIA6_CGSSE_IPZS001SNAPSHOT&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=4&_settoriQuotati_WAR_FSIA6_CGSSE_IPZS001SNAPSHOT_actionName=eseguiRicercaScioperiPerSettore&_settoriQuotati_WAR_FSIA6_CGSSE_IPZS001SNAPSHOT_settore=4%3A%3A%3ATrasporto+Pubblico+Locale)

You will need to translate the page, if you are in Google Chrome, you will be automatically prompted to do so. If not, go to google translate website and paste in the url of link 1.

If you are looking for a particular date when there may be strikes, your best bet would be to go to the below address.

[Search for Italian Strikes](http://www.cgsse.it/web/guest/ricerca-scioperi)

Here, you are able to search based on details you enter including date, location, sector etc. All fields are optional. Again, translate the page first. The sector you are likely interest in is "trasporto ferroviario" for trains and "Trasporto Pubblico Locale" for local public transport. In the list of strikes, clicking the symbol on the right will give you more details on the strike, especially the intended duration.

If you do not know any of the date, location or sector, link 1 will show you strikes in columns - the date, the location, the sector, details and location.

Link 2: [Italian Strike Information from Italia Rail](https://www.italiarail.com/strike-information)

In short, Itallians plan their strikes in advance. Details of when strikes are scheduled can be found on link 1. If there is a specific service you are wanting to check, please comment it below.

In response to your bonus question,

"If your train is providing local transport during essential services for the peak times (from 06:00 to 09:00 and from 18:00 to 21:00 Mon-Sat) these will be are guaranteed. Some long-distance trains are also guaranteed on all days including holidays."

"Essential services mean that you will be transported to your destination somehow asap, just not nessecarily on the same train as originally booked."

Comment: Could you perhaps quote some of the relevant parts of the link? Links tend to change/vanish and then the information is lost too :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both links are useful but could you please integrate them into your answer, i.e. how to use the first link (how to use the search and how to read the results) and summarize what is said in the second link?

Comment: See edits above @MarkMayo

Comment: Wikipedia article about the first link here: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commissione_di_garanzia_dell%27attuazione_della_legge_sullo_sciopero_nei_servizi_pubblici_essenziali

Comment: "Strikes in real-time": http://www.cgsse.it/web/guest/scioperi-in-tempo-reale You have to read it to believe it!

Comment: Same website as link 1 @Berwyn - useful for National strikes whereas link 1 covers them all. Your link also covers everything from hygiene strikes to magistrates - sounds like Italians like going on strike!

Comment: I know it's the same website. I was just exploring it. It's a great resource and you gave a great answer.

Comment: Shame that not all countries provide this resource @Berwyn

Comment: @NathanShoesmith that link is a great resource and is exactly what I was looking for, however your answer could be even better if you made some examples of how to use the site, e.g. what sectors to look at, and how to read the results. Would you mind editing your question for that?

Comment: Please see edits above. @mts

Comment: @NathanShoesmith thanks. I might make some edits myself including screenshots and pointing out sectors if you don't mind. +1 by the way :)

Comment: Ok thanks, no problem. Does this answer your question then? Please tick if so.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith I edited your answer to add some info on how to use the site. If you disagree please make a rollback of my edits. If you still want to pimp your answer you could include screenshots that show exactly how the site works.

Comment: I approve your edits. I can't really see that adding screenshots are going to make this process much more simple for people to understand